# Socket.io + JSON RPC how to use them together

Tags: javascript, socket.io, json-rpc

How can I use Socket.io and JSON RPC together? How can I get data from server? I.e I got this code and it's doesen't work:

```
socket.on('query', { jsonrpc: '2.0', "method": "getOrganizationList", "id": 1}, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: How does it fail? Error messages?

Comment: Nothing happend, blank console.